# IE is forcing client certificate request even if SSLVerifyClient none on apache

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

We have a customer that does not want anymore ssl client verification in their webapp.

We have an apache2 server in front of jboss that serves all requests for that webapp.

I have set SSLVerifyClient to none in apache config and restarted apache, and the first landing page does not request the certificate anymore, but there are some other pages inside the application that still  requests the client certificate.

This hapens only in IE in other browsers it works ok.

Is there some cache in IE that stores something and neads to be celared? I have already cleaned all history data an also the SSL cache but the problem still perists.

I have to mention that all requests are made to the same cname and that cname has one virtualhost settings on the apache server.

I also have to mention that this happens only on when I try to serve some office files trugh the applicatoin

the vhost settigns are like this:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/****_wildcard.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/****_wildcard.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_cert_bundle.crt

RequestHeader set X-ClientCert %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://****:8080/ retry=0 timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse / http://****:8080/
ServerName ****
```